# Can't login to MS SQL Server from other devices

Tags: sql-server

On my family's main computer, my MS SQL Server login works fine, but on my laptop, I get an error when using the same login: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpYSy.png


I've tried various solutions (enabling TCP/IP and Named Pipes, creating an inbound rule for TCP 1433 in firewall, making sure SQL Server Browser is running, etc.) but none of them have worked so far. I am able to log on my the local server on my laptop with no errors. to the If anyone could figure this out for me, I would really appreciate it. 


(Keep in mind that I am relatively new to the server side of programming)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but it turns out that my antivirus was messing with my internet connection, and Firewall was blocking sqlserver.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you posted with your question, it appears that the login and/or password is incorrect. When  you attempt to connect to the instance of SQL Server from your laptop, are you using the same SQL Server Login that you use on the "family computer"? It may be that at one time you saved the credentials on your laptop, and possibly the login and/or password has changed. Can you please verify the instance is the exact same, the login and the password are identical? Following that, you should either be able to connect, or will receive a different type of login error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect using the IP Address or the name of the server?  If you are using the name of the server then try starting the SQL Server Browser service.

It appears that it cannot find that server, so just as a test turn the firewall off (momentarily) for the server and see if that is what is blocking you.  If it is make sure that the firewall has a rule to allow the sqlserver.exe program to go through.